# Install on OSX fails with missing libboost_signals-mt.dylib

Tags: ros-groovy, osx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

have a problem with OSX and groovy installation.
Did anyone have to cope with this error?
Should be installed...

```
-- Build files have been written to: /Users/max/ros_ws/geometry_experimental/tf2/build
cd build && make -j -l2
[  0%] Built target rospack_genmsg_libexe
[  0%] Built target rosbuild_precompile
Linking CXX shared library ../lib/libtf2.dylib
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-pthread'
ld: library not found for -l:/usr/local/lib/libboost_signals-mt.dylib
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/54503/install-on-osx-fails-with-missing-libboost_signals-mt.dylib/) by [madmax](https://answers.ros.org/users/1492/madmax/) on ROS Answers with karma: 496 on 2013-02-06

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had the same problem, it appears some pkg-config files are incorrect in ROS. Check my previous question for the solution:

http://answers.ros.org/question/54437/boost-signals-library-not-found/

---

Originally posted by [Hansg91](https://answers.ros.org/users/1621/hansg91/) with karma: 1909 on 2013-02-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [madmax](https://answers.ros.org/users/1492/madmax/) on 2013-02-08**:
Can't find a file with : in it.

**Comment by [Hansg91](https://answers.ros.org/users/1621/hansg91/) on 2013-02-08**:
Do you get anything if you execute : cd ~/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/lib/pkgconfig && grep -r 'l:/usr' *

**Comment by [madmax](https://answers.ros.org/users/1492/madmax/) on 2013-02-08**:
I found some libs and I can compile more packages. But I get the same error again with rospack_genmsg_libexe ... Edit: Works now, have to delete CMakeCache files ...

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Does the file `/usr/local/lib/libboost_signals-mt.dylib` exist on your system?  If not you may need to ensure boost is installed correctly on your system.

If you have recently reinstalled or updated boost then you might have stale build state, so you can try cleaning your CMake cache and rebuilding your packages to ensure they have up-to-date information.

---

Originally posted by [WilliamWoodall](https://answers.ros.org/users/3078/williamwoodall/) with karma: 1626 on 2013-02-06

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [madmax](https://answers.ros.org/users/1492/madmax/) on 2013-02-08**:
Yes, boost is installed.